# split string (mixed with number, brackets and characters) in R

Tags: r, split

I have a string mixed with number, brackets and characters. I want to split them into different rows. What would be a possible way to do it? Thanks for your help.

For instance, the string is like `"3. abc4(). 3. efg3() a() 4.ed."`. 
Final results would look like the following:

```
3. abc4().
3. efg 3() a()
4. ed.
```

Comment: What is the rule/rationale for the splits?

Comment: I need to reformat the string based on the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a regular expression. Here's one such way

```
x <- "3. abc4(). 3. efg3() a() 4.ed."
m <- gregexpr("\\d\\..*?(?=\\s*\\d\\.|$)",x, perl=T)
v <- regmatches(x,m)[[1]]
v; #[1] "3. abc4()."    "3. efg3() a()" "4.ed."
```

So that gives a vector with each separate element. Then if you want you can combine them with a newline in between and then print that out (using `cat` otherwise the newlines print as "\n")

```
cat(paste(v, collapse="\n"))
# 3. abc4().
# 3. efg3() a()
# 4.ed.
```

If you are new to regular expressions, it may look a bit crazy, but it looks for a single digit, followed by a decimal. Then it does a non greedy match, stopping when what follows is either just spaces then another digit-period combo or the end of the string.

Comment: I have no knowledge on regular expression before. Your answer is very helpful. Thanks a lot. But how can I change the regular expression if the number is range from 0-115?

Comment: Well, regular expressions aren't great for specific ranges of numbers, but this will at least match more than one digit `m <- gregexpr("\\d+\\..*?(?=\\s*\\d+\\.|$)",x, perl=T)`